# Generating rotated bitmaps without resizing

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, rotation

I'm trying to build a ring from twenty copies of a single image, which is a 1/20th slice of the full ring. I generate bitmaps that are this original image rotated to their correct degree amounts. The original image is a 130x130 square

[image: original slice]

The code that generates the rotated slices looks like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.battery_green);
    FileOutputStream fos;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        String idName = "batt_s_"+i;
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        m.setRotate((i * 18)-8, bmp.getWidth()/2, bmp.getHeight()/2);

        Bitmap newBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), m, true);
        try {
            fos = context.openFileOutput(idName+"_"+color+".png", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
            newBmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        m.reset();
        BattConfigureSmall.saveInitPref(context, true);
    }
```

The ImageViews that these generated bitmaps are eventually being slotted into all have scaleType="center" in their XML. However, the generated output looks like this:

[image]

Not exactly a perfect ring. The slices themselves, if rotated correctly, do make a perfect ring, because in API level 11 and up I'm using the android:rotate XML attribute on these ImageViews, but I need to support API levels 7-10 as well, so can anybody give me some advice? Thank you.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using images rather than drawing an arc? That seems easier to me.

Comment: I've got a little glow effect going on and I'm just generally more comfortable working with image files, as far as creative control goes. Not to mention I already have the whole thing working on Android 3.x and up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the matrix with `createBitmap` for this scenario, it'll do some odd things with image sizing, I think. Instead, create a new `Bitmap` and `Canvas` then draw to it with the matrix:

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.battery_green);
FileOutputStream fos;
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
Matrix m = new Matrix();

for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    String idName = "batt_s_"+i;
    m.setRotate((i * 18)-8, bmp.getWidth()/2, bmp.getHeight()/2);

    Bitmap newBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBmp);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, m, paint);

    try {
        fos = context.openFileOutput(idName+"_"+color+".png", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        newBmp.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    m.reset();
    BattConfigureSmall.saveInitPref(context, true);
}
```

Comment: Should the first argument of drawBitmap be newBmp instead of bmp? Because newBmp is the Bitmap that gets compressed into a file. And related question, is your method still intended to actually do any writing to a file?

Comment: No, `bmp` is correct. You want to draw the old bitmap (but transformed by `m`) onto the new bitmap. The code I added does not write to a file, the code you already had (`newBmp.compress`) already does so. Just give it a shot and see if it works for you (I tried it out and it worked for me).

Comment: I'll be damned, that looks a lot better. The circle shape itself is perfect. The only problem is that the rotated images look very jagged. Is there a way to make the canvas anti-alias?

Comment: Yes, you can use `Paint.setAntiAlias(true)` and maybe `Paint.setDither(true)`. I'll update and you can see if it helps.

Comment: It didn't seem to do anything, nor did setDither. It looks okay as is, much better than it was before, and this method is just for Android 2.3 users and below, so unless you've got any other ideas for preventing the jaggedness I'll definitely accept your answer